# How to use multiple backends in priority for company-mode

Tags: company-mode

If I do

```
(setq company-backends '(company-tabnine company-capf company-yasnippet))
```

Then `company` will try `company-tabnine` to give me completions. If tabnine fails, it will try capf.
If instead I do

```
(setq company-backends '((company-tabnine company-capf company-yasnippet)))
```

Then `company` will yield completions from all of the backends at once, which is what I want. I think it has some internal guidelines for how to order the completions: which appear at the top.
But I want completions from tabnine always to be prioritized; at the top. Any way to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `:separate` keyword:

```
(setq company-backends '((company-tabnine :separate company-capf company-yasnippet)))
```